# Can not get shape of the pytorch model for pytorch -> tensorflow lite model conversion

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, nlp

I can not get shape of the pytorch model for pytorch -> tensorflow lite model conversion. I use BABERT chinese model and would like to use [torch2tflite](https://github.com/omerferhatt/torch2tflite) for tensforflow lite model format conversion.

Docs says it implies model shape to run the command:

```
python3 -m torch2tflite.converter
    --torch-path tests/mobilenetv2_model.pt
    --tflite-path mobilenetv2.tflite
    --target-shape 224 224 3
```

So I need to get this shape first. I wrote a simply python script to do this:

```
import torch;
 
def loadModel():
    model = torch.load("/home/gelassen/Downloads/chinese_babert-base/pytorch_model.bin")
    model_shape = list(model.parameters())[0].shape 
    print(model_shape)
    print("Model shape" + model_shape)

loadModel()
```

But it fails with exception:

```
/start.py", line 10, in loadModel
    model_shape = list(model.parameters())[0].shape 
AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'parameters'
```

I use the model from [this public repo](https://github.com/modelscope/AdaSeq/tree/master/examples/babert) I would appreciate any help with this issue.

p.s.
The context of this work is I want to split up chinese random text into separate words on the Android phone. Android support only **tensforflow lite** models. It is possible to provide custom model, but it should be converted to tensforflow lite format first.

I can not train a model on my machine as I faced CUDA OOM error - seems it requires GPU with at least 12gb of RAM. Training in cloud might be an option, but I am investigating first existing pre-trained models.

Comment: From the error you receive I guess what you are loading is only the `state_dicts` of the model and optimizer and not the model itself

Comment: In archive I downloaded there are ```config.json, pytorch_model.bin, vocab.txt```, I assume ```pytorch_model.bin``` is my model, isn't it?

Comment: Typically the .bin files contains the state dict which I further suspect since the type seems to be an `OrderedDict`. You will need to define an instance of the model which I guess you can find in the repository you linked and then load the weights. See for instance this related [link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-load-model-weights-that-are-stored-as-an-ordereddict/75500) on the PyTorch forum. You can let me know if the issue persists

Comment: I have been working on it for a passed hour or more and haven't figure out yet how to build this model. It is an Alibaba framework to simplify building and training of models. The model is instantiated over a factory aka ```Model.from_config()```. A config is supposed to be a ```config.json``` file supplied within archive. However within a factory there is a validation of necessary fields and this config lacks some of them which leads to the error. I will rise this as a question in that repo, likely I just missed something.